# does head input > output copy all invisible characters to the new file?

Tags: shell, text-processing, character-encoding, head

I need to grab the first lines of a long text file for some bugfixing on a smaller file (a Python script does not digest the large text file as intended). However, for the bugfixing to make any sense, I really need the lines to be perfect copies, basically byte-by-byte, and pick up any potential problems with character encoding, end-of-line characters, invisible characters or what not in the original txt. Will the following simple solution accomplish that or I'd lose something using the output of `head`?

```
head infile.txt > output.txt
```

A more general question on the binary copy with `head`, `dd`, or else is now posted [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/267354/101254).

Comment: `head` only get 10 lines by default, you missed the rest of file.

Comment: The question mentions grabbing the first few lines. Also, if I needed the whole file, I always had the original. Or could make a copy more easily.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

POSIX says that the input to [`head`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/head.html) is a *text file*, and [defines](http://view-source:http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_397) a text file:

> 3.397 Text File
>
> A file that contains characters organized into zero or more lines. The lines do not contain NUL characters and none can exceed `{LINE_MAX}` bytes in length, including the `<newline>` character. Although POSIX.1-2008 does not distinguish between text files and binary files (see the ISO C standard), many utilities only produce predictable or meaningful output when operating on text files. The standard utilities that have such restrictions always specify "text files" in their STDIN or INPUT FILES sections.

So there is a possibility of losing information.

Comment: This is great, thanks. Can you think of a superior tool for slicing a text file, then? (I am happy to edit or repost the question for that if you have an answer.)

Comment: Perhaps a custom tool (or a version of `head` which uses a less-strict definition of "text files").  If I had to rely on it, I'd write a Perl script.

Comment: you could use something like `dd` if you wanted, say, the first 10Kbytes of the file, for example: `dd if=input of=output bs=1024 count=10`.  it's not a line-based copy, but will give you a usable smaller subset of the original file.

Comment: You'd be better off raising another question about a specific tool, given the limitations in head (unless there's already one, which searching might reveal) rather than solve it in comments, which prevents other people from easily finding it later.

Comment: See the edit with the link to the new question.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently, `head` does indeed garble its input when it isn't a text file:

```
$ wc /bin/ls
   431   3454 126496 /bin/ls
$ head -n 431 /bin/ls > a
 wc a
   431   3447 125378 a
$ diff a /bin/ls
Binary files a and /bin/ls differ
$ md5sum /bin/ls a
42846aa64774a99f0f1feba36ec2e099  /bin/ls
de032f5aa5ef356fb7d5ab4dc622df2e  a
$ wc -c /bin/ls a
126496 /bin/ls
125378 a
```

Stéphane Chazelas makes a good point in the comments:

> `wc -l` reports the number of newlines. `/bin/ls` likely has more bytes after the last occurrence of `0xa`, which `head -n 431` won't output. GNU tools (which you seem to be using) generally can deal with binary data (NUL bytes and arbitrarily long lines).

So, the reason the output is wrong when using `head -n` is that there is extra data after the last `\n` character. Looking at the source code for GNU `head`, I can confirm that both the function that reads by lines and the one that reads by bytes, use the same `safe_open()` call, so there really shouldn't be any difference between what they are capable of returning. This would suggest that using the GNU implementation of `head` (as typically found in most non-embedded OSes using Linux) is quite safe.

However, it looks like it works correctly if you tell it to work on bytes instead of lines (from `man head`):

```
  -c, --bytes=[-]NUM
          print  the  first  NUM bytes of each file; with the leading '-',
          print all but the last NUM bytes of each file
```

With the `-c` option, it seems to create identical files:

```
$ wc -c /bin/ls
126496 /bin/ls
$ head -c 126496 /bin/ls > a
$
$ md5sum /bin/ls a
42846aa64774a99f0f1feba36ec2e099  /bin/ls
42846aa64774a99f0f1feba36ec2e099  a
```

This is also the same result as what is obtained by `dd`:

```
$ dd if=/bin/ls of=a bs=126496 count=1
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
126496 bytes (126 kB, 124 KiB) copied, 0.000469919 s, 269 MB/s
$ diff a /bin/ls
$
```

I can't point to any official documentation that specifies that when using the `-c` flag, it will always produce correct binary output, but it seems like a reasonable assumption to make.

Comment: Ah, good and bad news for me. So I can try the `-c` option, but then need to figure how many bytes are in the first n lines exactly. Or if I take a round number of bytes, would the result still work as a text file with only the last line garbled or dropped?

Comment: @László I would expect so, but I won't say I know for sure. That said, if your file does actually contain `\n` and is line based, I'm pretty sure `head` will act as promised. A simple test would be to i) `head -n N file > foo` to get the first N lines, then `wc -c foo` to get the bytes and `head -c $bytes file >b` to get the same number of bytes from the original file. Then, `diff a b` to see if the two methods produced identical files.

Comment: `wc -l` reports the number of newlines. `/bin/ls` likely has more bytes after the last occurrence of 0xa, which `head -n 431` won't output. GNU tools (which you seem to be using) generally can deal with binary data (NUL bytes and arbitrarily long lines).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas ah, I see. That makes sense. I was looking at the source for `head` and the function for `-c` and the one that reads lines both use `safe_read` so I couldn't see why one would fail and the other not. Having data after the last newline would explain it. Thanks.

Comment: @László pelase see update and the comment above. You are almost certainly fine using `head`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split(1)`. This will create a number of files that each correspond to a byte-correct slice of your file.

Example: `FILE=test ; split -b 1000 $FILE $FILE.split.` will create 1000-byte files test.split.aa and test.split.ab and so on, and `cat $FILE.split.* > $FILE.recompose` will yield a $FILE.recompose identical to the original $FILE. If your file is bigger than 1000*26*26 then you need to increase suffix-length (see `man split`)

With `split -l 100` it will put 100 lines per file. I am fairly confident this will be byte-correct.