# how to copy a piece of a text file byte-by-byte to another text file? dd, head, or?

Tags: text-processing, dd, character-encoding, head

I need to grab the first lines of a long text file for some bugfixing on a smaller file (a Python script does not digest the large text file as intended). However, for the bugfixing to make any sense, I really need the lines to be perfect copies, basically byte-by-byte, and pick up any potential problems with character encoding, end-of-line characters, invisible characters or what not in the original txt.

I think it is no problem for a text file to end mid-line, so copying some specific bytesize would accomplish what I intend to do. Both `head` and `dd` seem to be able to do this, but `man head` says to work on text files and `man dd` to copy the standard input to the standard output (and offer conversion tools), I could not verify that they do the copy bit-to-bit, without any conversion or loss. Thus the following two solutions seem to work in tests, but I am not sure I am testing them on any possible problem characters. A definitive answer or another preferable solution would be most helpful.

Either

```
dd if=input.txt of=output.txt bs=256 count=1
```

or

```
head -c 256 input.txt > output.txt
```

Also see the original, more specific question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/267320/101254).

Comment: Definitely dd is a exact byte by byte copy. You may want to consider adding a trailing new-line to the new file to make the last-part-of-a-line into a line.

Comment: The trouble with `dd` that I see is that since `dd` does not know about character encoding, it will happily stop in the middle of a multi-byte utf8 character.